# Make A Filter with select and jQuery on table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a filter using select to update a table, and it's working perfectly. But there is a problem: if I have more than one `select` at the time they don't work together.

This is my code (you can also see it in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vm1Lf8st/)):

```js
$('.filterselect').change(function () {
    _this = this;
    var main = this.name;
    $.each($("#table tbody tr").find("#"+main), function() {
        
        var label = $(this).closest('tr');
        if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) == -1 )
            $(label).hide();
        else
            $(label).show();                
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="filterselect" name="data1">
    <option></option>    
    <option>Ahmed</option>
    <option>Ralf</option>
    <option>Rami</option>
</select>
<select class="filterselect" name="data2">
    <option></option>    
    <option>20</option>
    <option>25</option>
    <option>27</option>
    <option>36</option>
    <option>45</option>
</select>     
<select class="filterselect" name="data3">
    <option></option>    
    <option>Amman</option>
    <option>USA</option>
    <option>Ukrania</option>
</select>     
<table id="table"> 
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">Ahmed</td>
            <td id="data2">36</td>
            <td id="data3">Amman</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">Ralf</td>
            <td id="data2">20</td>
            <td id="data3">USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">Saleem</td>
            <td id="data2">25</td>
            <td id="data3">Russia</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">Rami</td>
            <td id="data2">27</td>
            <td id="data3">USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">JACK</td>
            <td id="data2">36</td>
            <td id="data3">USA</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">emma</td>
            <td id="data2">26</td>
            <td id="data3">Usa</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">Tareq</td>
            <td id="data2">45</td>
            <td id="data3">Ukrania</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="data1">rana</td>
            <td id="data2">36</td>
            <td id="data3">Solvikia</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Example to reproduce the issue:

1. Pick age 36 in second `select`
2. Pick country USA in third `select`

It should display the information from people that is 36-years-old from the USA, but instead it displays all the people from the USA (only the last filter stands, ignoring the previous filters).

Comment: it only need to be connected together

Comment: You have duplicated (and triplicated id's in your code). Use classes instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue that was on your code is it only checks for single `select` field which was changed. You need to check for all 3 `select` fields to make it work.
Try the following:

```
 $('.filterselect').change(function () {
        $("#table tbody tr").each(function() {
            var ck1 = $(this).find('#data1').text().toLowerCase();
            var ck2 = $(this).find('#data2').text().toLowerCase();
            var ck3 = $(this).find('#data3').text().toLowerCase();
            var val1 = $('select[name="data1"]').val().toLowerCase();
            var val2 = $('select[name="data2"]').val().toLowerCase();
            var val3 = $('select[name="data3"]').val().toLowerCase();
            if(ck1.indexOf(val1)==-1 || ck2.indexOf(val2)==-1 || ck3.indexOf(val3)==-1)
                 $(this).hide();
            else
                 $(this).show();                
        });
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/subinmertz/vm1Lf8st/1/

Here it checks each row with all 3 `select` fields & then show / hide the row.

Comment: Thanks man so much .. u really solved a big problem ..